# std::initializer_list for parameter lists on C++11 literal operators

Tags: c++, c++11, literals

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal), only `const char *`, `unsigned long long`, `long double` , `char` and variations are allowed on literal operators:

```
// using std::chrono::seconds operator""s(unsigned long long);
auto sec = 30s;
// using std::string operator""s(const char*, std::size_t);
auto str = "hello"s;
```

I wonder, if we could take `std::initializer_list` as a parameters, we can expand it to make and STL container literal possible:

```
// using std::vector<int> operator""v(std::initializer_list<int>);
auto vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}v;
   
// using std::list<double> operator""l(std::initializer_list<double>);
auto list = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0}l;
```

Why does a literal operator have such a limitation on its parameter list? Is there some defect or complexity to take a `std::initializer_list` as a literal operator’s parameter?

Comment: What cppreference.com says is correct. You cannot create user-defined literals for `std::initializer_list` or `brace-init-list`. Only for strings and numerics. That is just the way the C++ standard defines it.